# How to delete unique item from local storage array? (Nothing has worked so far)

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am totally stuck.

I am working on the [Library project](https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/full-stack-javascript/courses/javascript/lessons/library) from The Odin Project's JavaScript course, and I am trying to use localStorage so that the user can save their "library" to, well, their local storage.

I've never been able to 100% successfully use localStorage before. It seems simple enough, but for some reason, there was some kind of block in my brain about how to utilize it correctly. This time, however, I was able to get my program to be able to 1) save the user's data (via a button click), 2) load it correctly into the individual "cards" on the page, and 3) delete the entire storage (via another button click). I am extremely excited about this... it feels so good to not know how to do something and then get it to work.

The one thing that has me totally confused is being able to delete a unique item from the localStorage array. When you click the "New Book" button on my page, a modal comes up, and you're required to enter a book's title, author, # of pages, and whether or not you have read it. There's also an option to set the background color. Clicking Submit will then generate a "card" with the book's information on it.

Each card has an X button in the corner. When the X button is clicked, the card is deleted from the page. I want it so that it (meaning that card's book's object) is also deleted from the local storage array (preferably without the user having to press the "Save to local storage" button again, although it isn't a dealbreaker).

Each time the user creates a new book, the book's details are saved as an object into an array called libraryBooks (which I then stringify so I can use localStorage). From my understanding, in order to be able to delete individual parts of the array, I need to use code that is something like this:

```
libraryBooks.splice(libraryBooks.indexOf(item), 1);
```

I think my issue is that I don't know how to get the item's index number. I'm not sure how to make it so that the program follows the instructions "When this X button is clicked, find that book's object in the array" if that makes sense. At this point, I've tried several things, and I'm just totally confused.

So yeah! Any help would be wonderful. I've gone through and commented my code to try to help clarify what everything does. I've included the entire thing so that I don't potentially leave something important out related to my problem, and so that it works in the code snippet. But in case it doesn't, here are links to the code repo and the live demo:

- [Live demo](https://risclover.github.io/TOP-Library/)
- [Code repo](https://github.com/Risclover/TOP-Library)

```js
// Link DOM elements
const newBookBtn = document.querySelector('.newbook'); // New Book button
const showBooks = document.querySelector('.show-books'); // div container
const cardClose = document.querySelectorAll('.cardclose'); // button to close card
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]"); // for popup boxes
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]"); // for popup boxes
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submitbtn'); // Submit button (in popup boxes)
const formBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.form-box'); // Form box within popup box
const formRadio1 = document.querySelector('#bookreadyes'); // Form radio buttons within popup box
const isVisible = "is-visible"; // for popup boxes
const colorDropdown = document.querySelector('select'); // Color-picking dropdown in popup boxes
let libraryBooks = [];

// localstorage buttons (save and delete)
const saveStorage = document.getElementById('save-storage');
const deleteStorage = document.getElementById('delete-storage');

// Button event listeners
saveStorage.addEventListener('click', updateLocalStorage);
deleteStorage.addEventListener('click', deleteLocalStorage);
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addBookToLibrary);


// If the 'books' key is empty, simply set libraryBooks to empty array.
if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) {
  libraryBooks = [];

  // Otherwise, set library books array to get items from the 'books' key
} else {
  const booksFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
  libraryBooks = booksFromStorage;
}


// The Book constructor
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title
  this.author = author
  this.pages = pages
  this.read = read
  this.info = function() {
    return `${this.title} by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages, ${read}`;
  }
}


// Add book to library function.
function addBookToLibrary() {
  let bookTitle = document.querySelector('#book-title');
  let bookAuthor = document.querySelector('#book-author');
  let bookPages = document.querySelector('#book-pages');
  let bookReadYes = document.querySelector('#bookreadyes')
  let bookReadNo = document.querySelector('#bookreadno');
  let alertWords = document.querySelector('.alertwords'); // Alert if form elements are empty
  let bookRead;


  if (bookReadYes.checked) {
    bookRead = 'Read';
  } else if (bookReadNo.checked) {
    bookRead = 'Not read';
  }

  // Creating a new book object via the Book constructor
  let newBook = new Book(bookTitle.value, bookAuthor.value, bookPages.value, bookRead);

  // If any form elements are empty, throw error and don't submit book. If none of them are empty, proceed.
  if (bookTitle.value.length === 0 || bookAuthor.value.length === 0 || bookPages.value.length === 0) {
    alertWords.textContent = 'Please fill in all fields.';
  } else {
    alertWords.textContent = '';
    document.querySelector('.modal.is-visible').classList.remove(isVisible); // Closes the modal
    formBoxes.forEach(formBox => {
      formBox.value = ""; // Sets the form values so they're blank the next time the New Book button is pressed
    });
    formRadio1.checked = true; // Set the radio buttons so that the "Yes" button is automatically selected (otherwise, the user's last choice will be selected)

    // Push the new book object into libraryBooks array
    libraryBooks.push(newBook);

    // The rest of the lines of code in this function create the actual book card on page
    const newCard = document.createElement('div');
    const newCardTitle = document.createElement('h4');
    const newCardAuthor = document.createElement('p');
    const newCardPages = document.createElement('p');
    const newCardRead = document.createElement('span');

    newCardTitle.setAttribute('class', 'title-style');
    newCardAuthor.setAttribute('class', 'author-style');
    newCardPages.setAttribute('class', 'pages-style');
    newCardRead.setAttribute('class', 'read-style');

    newCard.classList.add('isVisible', 'cardbox', colorPicker());
    showBooks.appendChild(newCard);

    for (let i = 0; i < libraryBooks.length; i++) {
      newCardTitle.innerHTML = `${libraryBooks[i].title}`;
      let closeBtn = "<button type='button' class='close-default' onclick='$(this).parent().parent().remove();'>x</button>";
      newCardTitle.innerHTML += closeBtn;
      newCardAuthor.innerHTML = `by ${libraryBooks[i].author}`;
      newCardPages.innerHTML = `<strong>Pages</strong>: ${libraryBooks[i].pages}`;
      newCardRead.innerHTML = `<strong>Status</strong>: ${libraryBooks[i].read}`;
    }

    newCard.appendChild(newCardTitle);
    newCard.appendChild(newCardAuthor);
    newCard.appendChild(newCardPages);
    newCard.appendChild(newCardRead);



  }
}



// Stuff for popup capability

for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const modalId = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(modalId).classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

// Keyboard shortvut for modal: ESC key to close
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if we press the ESC
  if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

cardClose.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    return false;
  });
})


// Switch function for setting the background color of the book's card
function colorPicker() {
  switch (colorDropdown.value) {
    case 'red':
      return 'cardback-red';
      break;
    case 'orange':
      return 'cardback-orange';
      break;
    case 'yellow':
      return 'cardback-yellow';
      break;
    case 'green':
      return 'cardback-green';
      break;
    case 'blue':
      return 'cardback-blue';
      break;
    case 'purple':
      return 'cardback-purple';
      break;
    case 'dark':
      return 'cardback-dark';
      break;
    case 'grey':
      return 'cardback-grey';
      break;
    default:
      return 'cardback-white';
      break;
  }
}


// Update local storage
function updateLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(libraryBooks));
}


// Delete local storage
function deleteLocalStorage() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  showBooks.textContent = "";
}


// Get localStorage data and set it to the variable "data"
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));

// Load the saved local storage objects into cards (almost identical to addBookToLibrary())
function loadLocalStorage(array, book) {
  let bookTitle;
  let bookAuthor;
  let bookPages;
  let bookRead;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    bookTitle = book.title;
    bookAuthor = book.author;
    bookPages = book.pages;
    bookRead = book.read;
  }

  // Create book card on page
  const newCard = document.createElement('div');
  const newCardTitle = document.createElement('h4');
  const newCardAuthor = document.createElement('p');
  const newCardPages = document.createElement('p');
  const newCardRead = document.createElement('span');

  newCardTitle.setAttribute('class', 'title-style');
  newCardAuthor.setAttribute('class', 'author-style');
  newCardPages.setAttribute('class', 'pages-style');
  newCardRead.setAttribute('class', 'read-style');

  newCard.classList.add('isVisible', 'cardbox', colorPicker());
  showBooks.appendChild(newCard);

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newCardTitle.innerHTML = `${bookTitle}`;
    let closeBtn = "<button type='button' class='close-default' onclick='$(this).parent().parent().remove();'>x</button>";
    newCardTitle.innerHTML += closeBtn;
    newCardAuthor.innerHTML = `by ${bookAuthor}`;
    newCardPages.innerHTML = `<strong>Pages</strong>: ${bookPages}`;
    newCardRead.innerHTML = `<strong>Status</strong>: ${bookRead}`;
  }

  newCard.appendChild(newCardTitle);
  newCard.appendChild(newCardAuthor);
  newCard.appendChild(newCardPages);
  newCard.appendChild(newCardRead);
}

// Required in order to load saved books onto page
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  loadLocalStorage(data, data[i]);

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #cedee9;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-height: 100%;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

input[type='text'] {
  font-size: .75rem;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.radio-option1 {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

h4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.close {
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(58, 84, 140);
}

.submitbtn {
  border: 1px solid rgb(58, 84, 140);
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(58, 84, 140);
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.submitbtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(40, 54, 85);
  border-color: rgb(40, 54, 85);
}

.book-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}


/* Testing this comment */

input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.bookcard {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cardbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 12px 20px 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 2px 6px 2px;
}

.alertwords {
  color: #df0a0a;
}

.show-books {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title-style {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.author-style {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pages-style,
.read-style {
  font-size: .9rem;
}

option {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

select {
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

#option-red,
.cardback-red {
  background-color: rgb(241, 191, 191);
}

#option-orange,
.cardback-orange {
  background-color: #ffcb9a;
}

#option-yellow,
.cardback-yellow {
  background-color: #fffda1;
}

#option-green,
.cardback-green {
  background-color: #9cd6af;
}

#option-blue,
.cardback-blue {
  background-color: #a1d3f0;
}

#option-purple,
.cardback-purple {
  background-color: #e6c1ff;
}

#option-grey,
.cardback-grey {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

#option-dark,
.cardback-dark {
  background-color: #282f52;
  color: white;
}


/* RESET RULES 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.close-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.btn-group {
  text-align: center;
}

.open-modal {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  background-color: rgb(40, 54, 85);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open-modal:active {
  background-color: rgb(40, 54, 85);
}

.open-modal:focus {
  background-color: rgb(40, 54, 85);
}


/* MODAL
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.781);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}

.modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.modal-dialog>* {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #a8c0f2;
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal p+p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


/* ANIMATIONS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

[data-animation] .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s var(--bounceEasing);
}

[data-animation].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

[data-animation="slideInOutDown"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutTop"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutLeft"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutRight"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

[data-animation="zoomInOut"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: scale(0.2);
}

[data-animation="rotateInOutDown"] .modal-dialog {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-1turn);
}

[data-animation="mixInAnimations"].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  animation: mixInAnimations 2s 0.2s linear forwards;
}

[data-animation="slideInOutDown"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutTop"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutLeft"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutRight"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="zoomInOut"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="rotateInOutDown"].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}

@keyframes mixInAnimations {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}


/* FOOTER
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.page-footer span {
  color: #e31b23;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Library</title>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2b4114baf6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Library</h1>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal1">
        New Book
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="open-modal" id="save-storage">
      Save local storage
    </button>
    <button class="open-modal" id="delete-storage">
      Delete local storage
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- Library books container -->
  <div class="show-books">

  </div>

  <!-- Modal code (popup box for new book form) -->
  <div class="modal" id="modal1" data-animation="slideInOutLeft">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <header class="modal-header">
        Book Details
        <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close>
          ✕  
        </button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-content">
        <form class="bookcard">
          <label>Title:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-box" id="book-title" placeholder="Fight Club">
          <label>Author:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-box" id="book-author" placeholder="Chuck Palahniuk">
          <label># of Pages:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-box" id="book-pages" placeholder="208" min="1" max="14000">
          <label>Have you read this book?:</label>
          <div class="radiobox">
            <label class="radio-option1"><input type="radio" name="read" value="yes" id="bookreadyes" class='form-radio' checked> Yes</label>
            <label class="radio-option2"><input type="radio" name="read" value="no" id="bookreadno" class='form-radio'> No</label>
          </div>
          <label>Select card color (optional):</label>
          <select class="colorpicker">
            <option value='default' selected disabled>Please select one</option>
            <option value="white">White (Default)</option>
            <option value="blue" id="option-blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="purple" id="option-purple">Purple</option>
            <option value="green" id="option-green">Green</option>
            <option value="grey" id="option-grey">Grey</option>
            <option value="red" id="option-red">Red</option>
            <option value="orange" id="option-orange">Orange</option>
            <option value="yellow" id="option-yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="dark" id="option-dark">Dark mode</option>
          </select>
          <p class="alertwords"></p>
        </form>
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-footer">
        <button class="submitbtn">Submit</button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer">
    <small>Made with <span>❤</span> by <a href="http://georgemartsoukos.com/" target="_blank">Sara Dunlop</a>
    </small>
  </footer>

  <!-- JS script -->
  <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Sara York. I recommend to reduce the amount of text and code in your questions keeping only the necessary to save time for the users who are willing to help you.

Comment: In your function that loads from localStorage, include the index as parameter i.e. `loadLocalStorage(data[i], i)`.

Comment: hi, if any of the **4** answers posted is your solution, be sure to mark 

Comment: I just updated my fixes there with a few refactorings, you can check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/otywdekm/4/

Comment: @TheBombSquad Please don't ask for acceptance. OP clearly knows how to accept answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I made a good couple changes to your script and it works
The **main problem** was that your close button wasn't given a listener that would be able to remove the book it's related to, solved that and also for fun added logic to automatically save to `localStorage`

The code's below but there's also a link to a **[working example](https://21d628b2-5791-40c7-af67-c3753d470e02.id.repl.co/)**

```js
// Link DOM elements
const newBookBtn = document.querySelector('.newbook'); // New Book button
const showBooks = document.querySelector('.show-books'); // div container
const cardClose = document.querySelectorAll('.cardclose'); // button to close card
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]"); // for popup boxes
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]"); // for popup boxes
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submitbtn'); // Submit button (in popup boxes)
const formBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.form-box'); // Form box within popup box
const formRadio1 = document.querySelector('#bookreadyes'); // Form radio buttons within popup box
const isVisible = "is-visible"; // for popup boxes
const colorDropdown = document.querySelector('select'); // Color-picking dropdown in popup boxes
let libraryBooks = [], automaticallyUpdate = true; //change automaticallyUpdate to false to prevent automatic saving(on changes)


// localstorage buttons (save and delete)
const saveStorage = document.getElementById('save-storage');
const deleteStorage = document.getElementById('delete-storage');

// Button event listeners
saveStorage.addEventListener('click', updateLocalStorage);
deleteStorage.addEventListener('click', deleteLocalStorage);
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addBookToLibrary);


// The Book constructor
function Book({title, author, pages, read, color}) {
  this.title = String(title)
  this.author = String(author)
  this.pages = Number(pages)
  this.read = read?"Read":"Not Read"
  this.color = String(color)
  this.info = function() {
    return `${this.title} by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages, ${this.read} with color ${this.color}`;
  }
}

//returns your close button with a listener that actually removes the book
//"<button type='button' class='close-default' onclick='$(this).parent().parent().remove();'>x</button>";
function closeBar(book){
  let btn=document.createElement('button')
  btn.className='close-default'
  btn.innerHTML='x' //wow almost forgot this
  btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    $(btn).parent().parent().remove()
    console.log(book,libraryBooks,libraryBooks.indexOf(book))
    libraryBooks.splice(libraryBooks.indexOf(book),1)
    if(automaticallyUpdate){updateLocalStorage()} //automatic saving
  })
  return btn //the button is returned to be placed in its arrangement
}


// Add book to library function.
function addBookToLibrary() {
  let color = colorDropdown.value;
  let bookTitle = document.querySelector('#book-title');
  let bookAuthor = document.querySelector('#book-author');
  let bookPages = document.querySelector('#book-pages');
  let bookRead = document.querySelector('#bookreadyes').checked; //true if checked, false if not checked
  let alertWords = document.querySelector('.alertwords'); // Alert if form elements are empty
    
  // Creating a new book object via the Book constructor
  let newBook = new Book({title:bookTitle.value, author:bookAuthor.value, pages:bookPages.value, read:bookRead, color});


  // If any form elements are empty, throw error and don't submit book. If none of them are empty, proceed.
  if (bookTitle.value.length === 0 || bookAuthor.value.length === 0 || bookPages.value.length === 0) {
      alertWords.textContent = 'Please fill in all fields.';
  } else {
      alertWords.textContent = '';
      document.querySelector('.modal.is-visible').classList.remove(isVisible); // Closes the modal
      formBoxes.forEach(formBox => {
          formBox.value = "";           // Sets the form values so they're blank the next time the New Book button is pressed
      });
      formRadio1.checked = true; // Set the radio buttons so that the "Yes" button is automatically selected (otherwise, the user's last choice will be selected)

      // Push the new book object into libraryBooks array
      libraryBooks.push(newBook);
      
      // The rest of the lines of code in this function create the actual book card on page
      const newCard = document.createElement('div');
      const newCardTitle = document.createElement('h4');
      const newCardAuthor = document.createElement('p');
      const newCardPages = document.createElement('p');
      const newCardRead = document.createElement('span');

      newCardTitle.setAttribute('class', 'title-style');
      newCardAuthor.setAttribute('class', 'author-style');
      newCardPages.setAttribute('class', 'pages-style');
      newCardRead.setAttribute('class', 'read-style');

      newCard.classList.add('isVisible', 'cardbox', colorPicker(newBook.color));
      showBooks.appendChild(newCard);

      const {title,author,pages,read}=newBook
      newCardTitle.innerHTML = `${title}`;
      let closeBtn = closeBar(newBook)
      newCardTitle.appendChild(closeBtn);
      newCardAuthor.innerHTML = `by ${author}`;
      newCardPages.innerHTML = `<strong>Pages</strong>: ${pages}`;
      newCardRead.innerHTML = `<strong>Status</strong>: ${read}`;
      
      
      newCard.appendChild(newCardTitle);
      newCard.appendChild(newCardAuthor);
      newCard.appendChild(newCardPages);
      newCard.appendChild(newCardRead);
      
      if(automaticallyUpdate){updateLocalStorage()} //automatic saving

   }
}



// Stuff for popup capability

for (const el of openEls) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const modalId = this.dataset.open;
        document.getElementById(modalId).classList.add(isVisible);
    });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
        document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
    }
});

// Keyboard shortvut for modal: ESC key to close
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    // if we press the ESC
    if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
        document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
    }
});

cardClose.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    });
})


// Switch function for setting the background color of the book's card
let colors = {red:1, orange:1, yellow:1, green:1, blue:1, purple:1, dark:1, grey:1}
//the above variable saves a lot of lines in the colorPicker function
function colorPicker(color) {
    if(!colors[color]){return 'cardback-white'}
    return 'cardback-'+color
}


// Update local storage
function updateLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(libraryBooks));
}


// Delete local storage
function deleteLocalStorage() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    showBooks.textContent = "";
}


// Get localStorage data and set it to the variable "data"
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))||[]
// the "||" in case there was nothing stored yet and it prevents an error from reading map from null
.map(book=>new Book( book )) //convert localStorage data to a list of "Book"s

// Load the saved local storage objects into cards (almost identical to addBookToLibrary())
function loadLocalStorage({title,author,pages,read,color}) {
    // EDIT: the for loops in this function are seemingly useless    
    var newBook=arguments[0]
    libraryBooks.push(newBook)
    // Create book card on page
    const newCard = document.createElement('div');
    const newCardTitle = document.createElement('h4');
    const newCardAuthor = document.createElement('p');
    const newCardPages = document.createElement('p');
    const newCardRead = document.createElement('span');

    newCardTitle.setAttribute('class', 'title-style');
    newCardAuthor.setAttribute('class', 'author-style');
    newCardPages.setAttribute('class', 'pages-style');
    newCardRead.setAttribute('class', 'read-style');
    
    newCard.classList.add('isVisible', 'cardbox', colorPicker(color));
    showBooks.appendChild(newCard);
     
    
    newCardTitle.innerHTML = `${title}`;
    const closeBtn = closeBar(newBook);
    newCardTitle.appendChild(closeBtn);
    newCardAuthor.innerHTML = `by ${author}`;
    newCardPages.innerHTML = `<strong>Pages</strong>: ${pages}`;
    newCardRead.innerHTML = `<strong>Status</strong>: ${read}`;
     
     newCard.appendChild(newCardTitle);
     newCard.appendChild(newCardAuthor);
     newCard.appendChild(newCardPages);
     newCard.appendChild(newCardRead);
}

// Required in order to load saved books onto page
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    loadLocalStorage(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for attempting to answer my question! I think there's a problem with the code you provided, however. I went to the working example link you provided to test it out, and it seems that, no matter which one you try to delete, it just deletes the last book in the array. So for example, if you have 4  books in the library and try to delete the 2nd one, it just deletes the last one. If you then try to delete the 2nd one again (which was previously the 3rd one), it just deletes the last one again. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: the problem was that when you load from `localStorage` the loader function isn't the one pushing objects to `libraryBooks`, so my auto save ends up doing `libraryBooks.splice(-1,1)`.. fixed. check it out when u can :D

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond. Your answer is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple fix for you

```
let closeBtn = `<button type='button' class='close-default' onclick='libraryBooks.splice(libraryBooks.findIndex((book) => book.title === "${bookTitle}" && book.author === "${bookAuthor}"), 1);'>x</button>`;
```

`i` is getting from your array list

Just in case you don't understand what is template literals, I share the link here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

I also added an extra fix for your `deleteLocalStorage`. You need to clean up your `libraryBooks` array too.

```
function deleteLocalStorage() {
  libraryBooks = [] //here is the fix to clean up your array
  window.localStorage.clear();
  showBooks.textContent = "";
}
```

You can check my fixes here

https://jsfiddle.net/otywdekm/4/

Comment: the question was to delete individual "books" btw and I checked the snippet and yours doesn't do this :{

Comment: Deleting a book with `x` button, isn't it? If you bother about deleting a book in local storage, just click on save local storage again.

Comment: I just did that, and it's still there, maybe jsfiddle is being weird? gonna try again a different way.. nope, apparently books still dont get deleted individually.. make a book, x off the book, click run again and see if the book u comes back as well

Comment: @TheBombSquad I know the reason for it, you have duplicated code for X button but I added my logic to only 1 place. I just updated my code here https://jsfiddle.net/jpethn4c/1/, you can try it again.

Comment: @TheBombSquad I also just updated my answer too, please let me know if you're still facing that problem

Comment: ah, naw problem is solved :D

Comment: if it's useful, please help me to upvote my answer, that will encourage me to contribute more to our community. Thank you! ^_< @TheBombSquad

Comment: Hey @NickVu. I'm pretty sure your solution works! Granted, the user does have to click on the "Save to Local Storage" button again, but perhaps I can figure out a way to fix that myself. Either way, there's a solution! Thank you very much. I'm going to run some tests to make sure it's actually solved, and then I'll set this as the answer to my question.

Comment: You're welcome!~ @SaraYork. If you want to have further discussion about how to solve that book deletion behavior, feel free to reach out to me. :D

Comment: Hey again @NickVu. So I found an error. I'm not sure if this was the case in the jsfiddle, but I applied your code to my actual file I'm working on. If you add an odd number of books (say, 3 books), you can delete the first book. However, if you add an even number of books (say, 4 books), trying to delete the 1st book actually deletes the 2nd book instead. There were a couple of other issues like this in other spots, too. What do you think is going on?

Comment: I just fixed your code again. You can check it out here. In the meanwhile, I also updated the link in the answer for your reference, @SaraYork

Comment: Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/otywdekm/4/

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your demo , and what I think you can do is, while saving a book object you can pass in an property called id to identify the exact book from the collection.

So when you click on the x button you will get the details of that book which now has an id and you can filter it out.

Something as follows -

```
const filteredBooks = existingBooks.filter((el) => el.id !== book.id);
localstorage.setItem('books', filteredBooks);
```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You Problem in delete specific book card**

```
libraryBooks.splice(libraryBooks.indexOf(item), 1);
```

Thats not correct because

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict
> equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals,
> operator).

libraryBooks.indexOf always results in -1

the solution you can add index when you create book in book constructor and increment it in every book

```
[
{
index: 0
author: "00"
pages: "200"
read: "Read"
title: "00"
}
]
```

when create new object set index++ to able get the object directly
and when delete

```
function deleteBook(book){
   libraryBooks.splice(book.index , 1)
}
```

Comment: valid point, however from where you can remove the html element, it's very easy to use the object whose data made the element to remove it from the `libraryBooks` array